# Close icon to left or right on mobile Material Design

Tags: interaction-design, design, human-interface-guideline

I have observed that Material Design puts the close icon to the left in all the examples of Material Design. Do you know any case that it goes to the right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific to rules of a specific interface - not general UX.

Comment: Do you have a specific UX problem you're working through, and a context of users trying to accomplish a goal?

Comment: Weeeell, to be fair, there are other questions about MD that have not been met with this criticism, e.g. [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/69696/why-the-textfield-in-google-material-design-without-box). @Alejandro Gomez Naranjo I guess if you specified your question better, for example "what are the benefitcs" etc., it would have more justification to be here.

Comment: @MikeM My doubt is that I am putting all the close icon to the left, as Material Design, but my Product Designer says it must be to the right..he says that it is always to the right, when MD is putting it to the left. I need to convince him! :)

Comment: @Big_Chair Well, for me, the benefits would be that if you put the close icon to the left, you have all the right area for putting different action icons and menu icons to play with. But if you put the close icon to the right, it will be isolated (as the close action is a critical one, it should be isolated to avoid some accidental OnTouch finger action)..

Comment: @AlejandroGomezNaranjo show us your specific mock that shows the context. When you say 'close action', are there several actions laid out? Having a simple visual will help

Answer (score 0):

No. If your application is strictly following the material design system, then the "Go Back" and "Close" buttons are placed to the left end of the top bar for LTR languages.

> The recommended placement of elements in a top app bar for left-to-right languages is:
>
> - Place navigation on the far left
> - Place any titles to the right of navigation
>
> ---
>
> *Here is a screenshot from the material design guidelines:*
>   [image]

.

An Exception usually seen that differs from the above-mentioned usage is when it comes to 'dialog boxes'. Here, The No Thanks button acts as the close button.
[image]